# SVNKit diff between dates

Tags: java, svn, diff, svnkit

I am trying to use SVNKit to do a simple: `svn diff url {date1}:{date2}`.
I cannot figure out how to use it on SVNKit. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVNKit's `SVNRevision` class has a static method that constructs it from java.util.Date instance, this is an analog of SVN's {date}.

To run diff

1 . Prepare diff generator that is responsible for formatting the patch (SVN format, Git format and GNU format (with SvnNewGenerator wrapper) are supported). The most interesting setting is base path --- all paths are relative to it, as it is possible (subversion always uses current path --- new File("") --- but you can use any other).

```
final SvnDiffGenerator diffGenerator = new SvnDiffGenerator();
diffGenerator.setBasePath(new File(""));
```

2 . Prepare output stream for the resulting patch

```
final OutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

3 . Run diff

```
final SvnDiff diff = svnOperationFactory.createDiff();
diff.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(url), SVNRevision.create(date1), SVNRevision.create(date2));
diff.setDiffGenerator(diffGenerator);
diff.setOutput(byteArrayOutputStream);
diff.run();
```

You can discover more settings by playing with SvnDiff and SvnDiffGenerator setters.

Comment: Did I ever tell you that you are my hero!? THANKS A LOT!!